# Completely Remove Date DST Conversions

Tags: date, dst

I have an odd situation where a client wants to display a date as-is without any Daylight Savings Time conversions. Basically, if they enter a specific date they want it to display as is (with the formatting intact).

How would I do this with EE? This was an EE 2.2 site that was recently upgraded to 2.7.3 so it includes the DST goodies; unfortunately they hate the new DST stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the DST thing, make sure admin is the desired timezone and base all new members on admins timezone.

Or just use @lows nice date plugin.

Answer (score 0):

DST is a nasty thing, I wish it simply didn't exist. You can always [force the timezone](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html#timezone) on front end dates. For back-end dates, it depends on both the system and user's localization settings.